# Overlapping geometry (Z - Fighting) solution with shader in Unity

Tags: unity, shaders, rendering, shaderlab

I have geometry that is overlapping with other geometry (the floor). So, I used a shader to bring my desired mesh to the top. However, a new problem arose: the shader was rendering not only on top of the floor but also on top of other objects. To address this issue, I utilized the render queue and set it to Geometry mode, assigning a specific number.

My question is: Is there any other efficient way to handle this? I mean, if two objects are experiencing z-fighting, can we resolve only those conflicts without affecting other objects?
[image]

```
Shader:
Shader "Custom/DepthBiasShader"
{
    Properties
    {
        _DepthBias ("Depth Bias", Range(0.0, 0.01)) = 0.005
        _Color ("Main Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1) // Default white color
    }

    SubShader
    {
        Tags { "RenderType"="Opaque" }

        Pass
        {
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag

            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            struct appdata
            {
                float4 vertex : POSITION;
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            struct v2f
            {
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
                UNITY_FOG_COORDS(1)
                float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
            };

            float _DepthBias;
            fixed4 _Color;

            v2f vert(appdata v)
            {
                v2f o;
                o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                o.uv = v.uv;
                UNITY_TRANSFER_FOG(o,o.vertex);
                return o;
            }

            half4 frag(v2f i) : SV_Target
            {
                // Apply color property
                half4 col = _Color;
                // Apply depth bias
                float depth = LinearEyeDepth(i.vertex.z / i.vertex.w); // Calculate depth in view space
                float bias = _DepthBias * depth;
                clip(i.vertex.z - bias);
                return col;
            }
            ENDCG
        }
    }

    FallBack "Diffuse"
}
```

Comment: Have you looked into [the Offset shader command described here](https://docs.unity3d.com/2020.1/Documentation/Manual/SL-CullAndDepth.html)? This lets you apply a small bias to an object's depth value, with the bias adjusted by view angle, to help it render on top of an otherwise co-planar surface, while still sorting mostly correctly against other geometry.

Comment: Yeah we checked it turning it off. I will share the screenshot

Comment: Your code does not show how you've attempted using the Offset command. If you need help with it, please describe what help you need.

Comment: What is the use for this? Is there a very specific reason you need this other mesh, whats wrong with moving it up or down a tiny amount or just using one?

Comment: @DMGregory Sorry i am not a shader guy i thought that dept thing is same like offset. Let me do an attempt with genAI. Then i will update

Comment: @Pow This is only for representation purposes. Actual i have several object which are placed on floor.

Comment: I recommend not copying and pasting AI-generated code that you don't understand. In this case, the AI is giving you bad advice and the shader shown here is not a good direction to pursue to solve this problem. Instead, if you have a question about how to use the Offset command, **ask a human that question** using this site, and you can get a tailored answer from someone who understands the topic.